# Why does my code exit with exit code: 0 even though the loop condition is still valid?

Tags: c, fork, execvp, unistd.h

I am trying to use `fork` with `execvp` to run two shell commands concurrently. I have two problems which are when I input `mkdir folder1&mkdir folder2`, it creates a folder named `folder1` and another folder named `folder2?` (the question mark is included in the folder name). The other problem is that the code exits after performing the two commands.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 80 /* The maximum length command */

int main(void) {
    char *args [MAXLINE / 2 + 1]; /* command line arguments */
    char *line = (char *) malloc((MAXLINE + 1) * sizeof (char));
    char *firstCommand = (char *) malloc((MAXLINE + 1) * sizeof (char));
    char *secondCommand = (char *) malloc((MAXLINE + 1) * sizeof (char));
    int shouldrun = 1; /* flag to determine when to exit program */
    pid_t pid;
    while (shouldrun) {
        printf("osh>");
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(line, MAXLINE, stdin);
        if (strncmp(line, "exit", 4) == 0) {
            shouldrun = 0;
        } else {
            firstCommand = strsep(&line, "&");
            secondCommand = strsep(&line, "&");
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0) {
                // child
                if (secondCommand != NULL) {
                    char *token;
                    int n = 0;
                    do {
                        token = strsep(&secondCommand, " ");
                        args[n] = token;
                        n++;
                    } while (token != NULL);
                    execvp(args[0], args);
                }
            } else {
                // parent
                char *token;
                int n = 0;
                do {
                    token = strsep(&firstCommand, " ");
                    args[n] = token;
                    n++;
                } while (token != NULL);
                execvp(args[0], args);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

## UPDATE 1:

I tried to follow Kevin's answer. I am trying to execute multiple processes concurrently, e.g. `ps&ls&who&date`. I tried a recursive method which gave me the same behavior. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 80 /* The maximum length command */

void execute(char *command) {
    char *args [MAXLINE / 2 + 1]; /* command line arguments */
    char *parentCommand = strsep(&command, "&");
    pid_t pid = fork();;
    if (pid == 0) {
        // child
        if (command != NULL) {
            execute(command);
        }
    } else {
        // parent
        char *token;
        int n = 0;
        do {
            token = strsep(&parentCommand, " ");
            args[n] = token;
            n++;
        } while (token != NULL);
        execvp(args[0], args);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char *line = (char *) malloc((MAXLINE + 1) * sizeof (char));
    int shouldrun = 1; /* flag to determine when to exit program */
    while (shouldrun) {
        printf("osh>");
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(line, MAXLINE, stdin);
        if (strncmp(line, "exit", 4) == 0) {
            shouldrun = 0;
        } else {
            execute(line);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the first part of your question but I see 1 call to `fork` and 2 calls to `execvp`. If successful, `execvp` will not return. Nothing will get back to run the loop again.

Comment: @Kevin That makes sense, then how to perform `execvp` and come back to the loop?

Comment: See my answer for it.

Comment: You're still calling `execvp` in the parent. Stop doing that.

Comment: @melpomene May you mention the reason, please? I used `system` function instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the first question, you need to truncate the `\n` from the line. Regarding the second question, you can use `system` function from `stdlib.h` header file which will not terminate your program.

Answer (score 1):

For your question about why it doesn't loop, you're calling `fork` once but calling `execvp` twice. If successful, `execvp` will not return. Nothing will get back to run the loop again. What you need to do is call `fork` once for each `execvp`. I suggest you move the `fork` and `execvp` calls to a separate function:

```
void run_command(const char* command) {
    /* I suggest you also check for errors here */
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        /* get args, call execvp */
    }
}

/* in your loop */
run_command(firstCommand);
run_command(secondCommand);
```

Comment: In this case, the two commands will not run concurrently, I want to enter two shell commands with an ampersand between them and run them concurrently by using forking.

Comment: Why do you think they won't run concurrently? My code doesn't include any waiting.